# No puedo utilizar jedi en geany

Tags: python-3.x, ide

Estoy utilizando geany en linux mint 20.3
He descargado de github geany-jedi-complete para usarlo, pero al seleccionarlo en el Administrador de Complementos se aborta el programa y genera el siguiente error en consola.

```
bash
/.config/geany/plugins/jedi-complete/jediserver.py", line 11, in <module>
    import jedi
ImportError: No module named jedi
Abortado (`core' generado)
```

Si ejecuto jediserver.py en consola, no aparece el error o si por ejemplo `$ python3 -c 'import jedi'` carga bien el módulo.
No encuentro que está fallando.
En las etiquetas no figura **geany** ni **jedi**

Comment: Buen día, si tienes más de una versión de Python instalada es probable que Geany esté utilizando una y sea otra en tu consola, intenta primero revisar si las versiones son iguales.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato (Perdón, no se cómo se hace refencia al usuario) El ` $ import jedi ` lo hago dentro de la consola o terminal de geany y no da error. No encuentro algún archivo de configuración de geany que me indique que versión de python utiliza.